# R: Adding columns / manipulating a data frame

Tags: r

I am trying to categorize a data set by grouping the **Months** column(with variables 1-12) into four groups. Winter(1-3), Spring (4-6), Summer(7-9) and Fall(10-12). I want to add in a NEW column, that will donate each entry to one of the seasonal groups.

```r
> head(weather_grouped)
# A tibble: 6 x 8
  Name       Province      Region `Date/Time` **Month**  Year `Mean Temp` year_range
```

Essentially I am looking to add in another column titled "Season", according to the number in the **Month** column

Comment: Understood your needs, but what is your question? Did you try to do your last sentence?

Comment: Try `weather_grouped$season <- rep(c("Winter","Spring","Summer", "Fall"), each = 3)[weather_grouped$month]`

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the `cut` function as follows:

```
   library(dplyr)
   weather_grouped %>% 
          mutate(season = cut(Month, breaks = c(-Inf,3,6,9,Inf), labels = c("Winter","Spring","Summer", "Fall"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is to use the `case_when` function:

```
    weather_grouped %>% mutate(season = case_when(Month <= 3  ~ "Winter",
                                                  Month <= 6  ~ "Spring",
                                                  Month <= 9  ~ "Summer",
                                                  Month <= 12 ~ "Winter",
                                                  TRUE        ~ "Unknown Season")
```